# Spotify Open Audio Player

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Currently I can play spotify tracks. I'm able to listen tracks. But what if I want to open an audio player just like spotify does & want to see the player with its controls along with listening?
My code goes here :

```
// Invoked by clicking the Cell in the UI.

// arrfileteredURL -> list of track urls 

NSURL *trackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrfileteredURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
NSLog(@"trackURL > %@",trackURL);
[[SPSession sharedSession] trackForURL:trackURL callback:^(SPTrack *track)
 {
     if (track != nil)
     {
         [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *tracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks) 
          {
              [self.playbackManager playTrack:track callback:^(NSError *error)
               {
                   if (error)
                   {
                       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot Play Track" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                       [alert show];
                   } else 
                   {
                   }
               }];
          }];
     }
 }];
```

What playbackManagerWillStartPlayingAudio will do?? It will just play an audio or will enable user to see the player also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playbackManagerWillStartPlayingAudio` just tells you that noise has started being delivered to the speakers/headphones/etc.

CocoaLibSpotify doesn't come with any player UI. If you want this, you'll have to build it yourself.